# Can Windows Kerberos be used to verify request origin?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, windows-authentication, kerberos

I have a slightly unusual Kerberos use-case.

My client software runs on Windows desktops and sends requests to a remote service. The remote service then forwards the requests to other services, which execute them as the client using delegation tokens.

However, some of the services are run on the client machines. These do not need to use delegation (they are already running as the client) but they should be authenticated (to prevent a user from executing tasks on another user's machine). The client services are not registered with SPNs.

I want my client services to be able to verify that a request came from itself.

If I were rolling my own system, I would `hmac` the request with a secret key on the client side, but I would much rather use existing Windows protocols.

**Can the Kerberos classes in .NET achieve this functionality?**